# unbind port of crashed program

Tags: linux, tcp, socket, udp

is there any way to unbind a port that was previously binded by a program that crashed at some time?
I don't like to reboot the development-machine every hour.

Comment: Restarting the network service should work. In Linux, it's rarely necessary to reboot a machine.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a program has connections, and after you kill the process, a timeout can be defined for the port to linger.

The involved kernel variables to change that timeouts are:

From: [Linux TCP Tuning](http://www.linux-admins.net/2010/09/linux-tcp-tuning.html)

> `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_tw_reuse`  -  This allows reusing sockets in
>   TIME_WAIT state for new connections when it is safe from protocol
>   viewpoint. Default value is 0 (disabled).
>   `/proc/sys/net/ipv4/tcp_fin_timeout` - This setting determines the
>   time that must elapse before TCP/IP can release a closed connection
>   and reuse its resources. During this TIME_WAIT state, reopening the
>   connection to the client costs less than establishing a new
>   connection. By reducing the value of this entry, TCP/IP can release
>   closed connections faster, making more resources available for new
>   connections.

You can change it temporally with:

```
sudo sysctl -w sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
sudo sysctl -w sudo sysctl -w net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
```

Or to add the configuration permanently, edit `/etc/sysctl.conf` and add:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout=30
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse=1
```

Thus, it will be applied at boot time too.

For further guidance, please read: [Reduce TIME_WAIT socket connections](http://www.linuxbrigade.com/reduce-time_wait-socket-connections/)

At application level, you can also specify the SO_REUSEADDR when opening the sock per this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767292/how-do-i-close-a-port-in-a-case-of-program-termination

As dr01 states, another alternative is doing manually:

```
service networking restart
```